# Fill up rows to count

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I got the result of a query, and want to join it with a mockup table to fill the rows up to a certain number. this is an example where the query has two rows as result, but i always want that to fill it up to 5 (see column *slot*)

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE …
```

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| jhkl | jol |
| das | das |

result:

| slot | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhkl | jol |
| 2 | das | das |
| 3 | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| 4 | *NULL* | *NULL* |
| 5 | *NULL* | *NULL* |

You help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh I would consider MySQL 8.x the default version now, since MySQL 5.x is reaching end of life in less than a year now.

Comment: unfortunatelly is ist still version 5.7

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE to produce exactly 5 rows every time. For example:

```
with recursive g (n) as (select 1 union all select n + 1 from g where n < 5)
select g.n as slot, x.foo, x.bar
from g
left join (select t.*, row_number() over() as rn from t) x on x.rn = g.n
```

Result:

```
 slot  foo   bar  
 ----- ----- ---- 
 1     abc   def  
 2     ghi   jkl  
 3     null  null 
 4     null  null 
 5     null  null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qKK03pfu).

Comment: An interesting side note: If it's not intended to always fill up to 5 rows (although this seems to be the case here), but to always add 3 rows at the end, you can replace the 5 with (select count(*) +3 from t)

Comment: @JonasMetzler You could be right, but I didn't get that impression from the OP's explanation.

Comment: No, I agree. Just wanted to mention that because I think that's good to know if someone looks for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should work on MySQL 5.7:

```
select s.slot, f.foo, f.bar
from 
(select @row:=0) as _init
cross join (
  select 1 as slot union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
) as s
left outer join
(
  select @row:=@row+1 as slot, foo, bar from foo
) as f using (slot);
```

Output:

```
+------+------+------+
| slot | foo  | bar  |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | jhkl | jol  |
|    2 | das  | das  |
|    3 | NULL | NULL |
|    4 | NULL | NULL |
|    5 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: If you ask how to make this simpler or easier, my reply will be "upgrade to MySQL 8.0."